# Weird bug with 1.1 usb hub after last Ubuntu 14.04 update in 20150606

Tags: usb, updates

I'm using Kubuntu Trusty LTS (32 Bit). uname -a: Linux xxxxxxxx-netbook 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:28 UTC 2015 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
I've updated several packages, here comes the list [[https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm2l4tpe24lu150/UpdateList?dl=0]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm2l4tpe24lu150/UpdateList?dl=0).

I thought it was a plain usb problem and I used:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
in
/etc/default/grub
And I used update-grub; restarted the computer with not the desired effect.

I've used dmesg to figure it out, here comes the output [[https://www.dropbox.com/s/7meqty6cqnbfko1/dmesg.log?dl=0]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7meqty6cqnbfko1/dmesg.log?dl=0).
But I don't know which one is the exact problem and how to fix it.

The same has happend with my laptop, so fixing the netbook will fix the laptop.

By the way, last update had issues with xorg, but fixed them.
That usb hub is very important, I connect to it my keyboard, mouse, the printer and a scanner.

Thanks in advanced.